# How do I limit the number of devices connected by users in my Node.js application?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have an application in React and NodeJs, I use Express, I want a way to control the number of devices that each user can connect per account, for example:
**User Jonh is entitled to two devices, so he can only log in on his PC and phone.**

How can I do this?

I tried searching for session control, but didn't find much.

I hope for a way to control the number of devices per user

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.